# How to change select option value as a dropdown <a></a> tags for font-style script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a select option tag here to change the font style of my text area.

However, this look doesn't match my tool and I would like it to be inside of a Bootstrap dropdown instead.

I would like for this:

```js
//Font select
const fontsSelect = document.getElementsByClassName('fonts-select')[0],
    styledTextArea = document.getElementsByClassName('styledTextarea')[0];
    fontsSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    styledTextArea.style.fontFamily = fontsSelect.value;

});
```

```html
<select class="form-control form-control-sm fonts-select">
    <option selected disabled>Select font...</option>
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Cambria">Cambria</option>
    <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
    <option value="Calibri">Calibri</option>
    <option value="Futura">Futura</option>
    <option value="Franklin Gothic">Franklin Gothic</option>
    <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
    <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
    <option value="Rockwell">Rockwell</option>
    <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
    <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>
            
<textarea class="styledTextarea" rows="15" placeholder="Write something.."></textarea>
```

To look something like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdowntools" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Fonts</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu fonts-select" aria-labelledby="dropdowntools">

<a selected disabled>Select font...</a>
<a value="Arial">Arial</a>
<a value="Cambria">Cambria</a>
<a value="Courier">Courier</a>
<a value="Calibri">Calibri</a>
<a value="Futura">Futura</a>
<a value="Franklin Gothic">Franklin Gothic</a>
<a value="Garamond">Garamond</a>
<a value="Helvetica">Helvetica</a>
<a value="Rockwell">Rockwell</a>
<a value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</a>
<a value="Verdana">Verdana</a>

</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I've been trying to experiment with it with no luck. I couldn't figure out how can I target this `styledTextArea.style.fontFamily = fontsSelect.value;` to instead be a "link value"

Can this be done without a submit button?

I would reallllly appreciate any help. Thank you!

**EDIT:** [Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twxhkpgv/) using select option
And [here's the output](https://jsfiddle.net/twxhkpgv/1/) I'd like to achieve

Comment: can you make a fiddle for this?

Comment: Hi @muzazu I edited my post to include a fiddle

Comment: @ixcode hi I update the fiddle, you can check it here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muzazus/bkx0Lqn7/17/) , my approach is to add `eventlistener` (click) to each `dropdown-item`.

Answer (score 0):

@ixcode, you are not having any submit button so that the program will change the font style.

Comment: Yes but you would have to use a live reload functionality.